# The componentDidMount is not getting called in reactjs

Tags: json, facebook, reactjs

I'm trying the example in reactjs tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html to read the json from server(file). But, my "componentDidMount" is not getting called.

Below is the code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this),
        cache: false
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: {}};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />         
      </div>
    );
  }
}); 

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) {

      return (
        <Comment pageName={comment.xyz} key={comment.id}>
          {comment.abc}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentpageName">
          {this.props.pageName}
        </h2>
        <p> {this.props.children} </p>        
      </div>
    );
  }
});
    ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox url="/api/comments" />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Please check the way I have initialized the data(data: {})

The "componentDidMount" gets called when the json is of the following type(Just the way in the tutorial):

```
[       {"id": "1", "xyz": "xyz1", "abc": "abc1"},
        {"id": "2", "xyz": "xyz2", "abc": "abc2"}   ]
```

But the json format I want is:

```
{
    content: [
    {"id": "1", "xyz": "xyz1", "abc": "abc1"},
    {"id": "2", "xyz": "xyz2", "abc": "abc2"},
    {"id": "3", "xyz": "xyz3", "abc": "abc3"}],
    "totalPages":3,
    "totalElements":10,
    "last":true
}
```

Let me know in what conditions the componentDidMount doesn't get called. Please help.

In the "Networks" console of chrome developer tools, I don't see the call made to my json file. 
When I added logs in my program, I see that getInitialState() gets called first, then render, then the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null" is shown.

Comment: Your desired JSON is not valid. Your keys need to be strings `"content":`

Comment: You're probably getting an error in the console about it.

Comment: @azium, I'm not getting any error as such in the console. Tried out the way you said as well. Things are still the same.

Comment: Your code works.. here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/40792/ Either you are in fact getting errors in the console or you're missing something from your question. You should set initial state to have `data: { content: [] }` though

Comment: @azium, I'm new to jsfiddle as well. Where is the json file in your https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/40799/ program?

Comment: I didn't include one.. you said the problem was that `componentDidMount` wasn't getting called, but you can see from the fiddle that it is.

Comment: Json is the issue here. Infact, my program is working for the fist json(that I've mentioned in the question). That is, the componentDidMount gets called without the json also(probably, I haven't tried) or for the first json format. It is not getting called for the second json format. Also, look at the second json format. That is the reason why I initialized data: {}

Comment: The code the *exact* way you have written will throw an error in the console `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` because `data` does not contain a `content` array on page load.

Comment: You should use `debugger` statement in `componentDidMount` then you can find out what the actual problem is.. I don't believe you're not getting console errors, or something else is missing from your example. If you want more help than this, provide more data. "Not working" is not enough detail.

Comment: @azium, thanks for spending your valuable time with me. Updated the question with the description of logs.

Comment: @azium, Thanks. I've upvoted a comment of yours. That worked. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your `componentDidMount()` is not called because your render code inside `<CommentList>` does not work on first render, because data is empty, and `this.props.data.content` probably does not exist, therefore your render fails.

What you probably should do is change this:

```
var commentNodes = this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) {
```

To this:

```
var commentNodes = [];
if (this.props.data.content) {
  commentNodes = this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) {
  ...
}
```

`componentDidMount()` is always called after the first render (and not in subsequent renders)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @wintvelt. Tried out your suggestion. It's still not calling the componentDidMount(). Now it says, "Cannot read property 'data' of null".

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake. Updated my answer.

Comment: Went ahead with your suggestion. It worked. I was getting the props.data as null. The code is:                                                                                   if (this.props.data != "'') {
                var commentNodes = this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) { ..... } }